# How to make htop sort by PID

Tags: linux, process, htop

How can you make htop sort the list of processes by PID?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
htop --sort-key PID
```

appears to work.  Found it via htop --help.

```
htop --sort-key help
```

shows a list of all the column keys.

Answer (score 13):

Press `F6` and select `PID`...

Comment: Is there another way without having to press F6?

Comment: @OSX Press `>`.

Comment: That causes the program to crash.

Comment: @OSX It works on my machine and is documented in [htop's man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/htop). It *would* work if you didn't have another issue.

Comment: I'm going to upvote you only because I think the OP is a little stingy here - there's nothing wrong with F6, and almost keyboard where it doesn't exist (with few exceptions).

Comment: I'm using an external keyboard, and F6 is assigned to do something else. In order to use F6 as a function key, I have to press the Fn button, but that's not on the external keyboard.

Comment: @OSXJedi As I wrote before, press `>` (greater than) instead.